User details doesn't get registered in firebase when signing in from my Flutter app
I'm developing a mobile app using Flutter and use Firebase for backend services. I'm using Firebase Authentication for authentication. The method is email and password. However when signing up the user I also store the device ID along with the user ID(the user ID given when signed in to firebase authentication) in a Firestore Database document.

The problem I'm having is when the details are entered and the button is clicked to sign up the user details doesn't get registered in Firebase Authentication and the device ID along with the user ID doesn't get saved in the database as well. I'm using try-catch statements and log statements to find the code but none of them show up in the console. I tried Authentication separately(without saving the device ID), then the user details gets registered in Firebase Authentication.

Here are the codes I'm using:

auth_service.dart - This file contains the methods for sign up/log in
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:exif_toolkit/authentication/device_details.dart';
import 'package:exif_toolkit/models/devices.dart';
import 'package:exif_toolkit/services/database_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final _deviceId = DeviceDetails().getDeviceId();
  final _databaseService = DatabaseService();

  Future<User?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final credentials = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      final userId = credentials.user?.uid;
      final deviceId = await _deviceId;

      if (userId != null && deviceId != null) {
        final device = Device(userId: userId, deviceId: deviceId);
        await _databaseService.addDevice(device);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error: userId or deviceId is null during signup.');
      }
      return credentials.user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        log('Sign up error: ${e.code} - ${e.message}');
        rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      log('Unexpected Sign Up Error: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<User?> loginUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final cred = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      final userId = cred.user?.uid;
      final deviceId = await _deviceId;

      if (userId != null && deviceId != null) {
        final isRegistered =
            await _databaseService.isDeviceRegistered(userId, deviceId);
        if (!isRegistered) {
          await signOut();
          throw Exception('This device is not registered for this account.');
        }
      return cred.user;
      } else {
        log("Error: userId or deviceId is null during login.");
        throw Exception('Login failed due to missing credentials.');
      }
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        log('Log In Error: ${e.code} - ${e.message}');
        rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      log("Log In Error Detected: $e");
      rethrow;
    }
    return null;
  }

  FutureOr<void> signOut() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      log('Sign out error detected');
    }
  }


**device_details.dart** - This file contains the method to get the device ID

*Note: This is AI generated(Google Gemini).*
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class DeviceDetails {
  //Get device ID
  Future<String?> getDeviceId() async {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    String? deviceId;

    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
        deviceId = androidInfo.id;
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
        deviceId = iosInfo.identifierForVendor;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error getting device ID: $e');
      }
    }
    return deviceId;
  }
}


**devices.dart** - data model for Firestore database document
class Device {
  String userId;
  String deviceId;

  Device({required this.userId, required this.deviceId});

  Device.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
            userId: json['userId'] as String,
            deviceId: json['deviceId'] as String);

  Device copyWith({String? userId, String? deviceId}) {
    return Device(
        userId: userId ?? this.userId, deviceId: deviceId ?? this.deviceId);
  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {'userId': userId, 'deviceId': deviceId};
  }
}


database_service.dart - Connection between flutter app and firestore database

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:exif_toolkit/models/devices.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

const String DEVICE_COLLECTION_REF = 'devices';

class DatabaseService {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  late final CollectionReference<Device> _deviceRef;

  DatabaseService() {
    _deviceRef = _firestore
        .collection(DEVICE_COLLECTION_REF)
        .withConverter<Device>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Device.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (device, _) => device.toJson());
  }

  /*Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDevices() {
    String? userId = _auth.currentUser?.uid;

    if (userId == null) {
      return const Stream.empty(); // Handle case where user is not signed in
    }

    return _deviceRef.where('userId', isEqualTo: userId).snapshots();
  }*/

  Future<void> addDevice(Device device) async {
    String? userId = _auth.currentUser?.uid;

    if (userId == null) {
      throw Exception('User is not signed in, cannot add device');
    }

    device = device.copyWith(userId: userId);
    try {
      await _deviceRef.add(device);
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error adding device to Firestore: $e');
      // Consider rethrowing or returning a Future with an error
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isDeviceRegistered(String userId, String deviceId) async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _deviceRef
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
        .where('deviceId', isEqualTo: deviceId)
        .get();

    return snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty;
  }
}

Please help me fix this issue. I need to register the user via Firebase Authentication and save the device ID along with user ID.
